# Hide information during bash debug run

Tags: linux, bash

We do debug run(bash -x ./my_script.sh) in a shell script to understand/show what it is doing. But in doing so it might show some sensitive information that I dont want to be visible, such as passwords. My script extracts the password from a secure vault and passes it as a variable within the script when required.

So, I want to understand if there is a way to hash/hide such sensitive information during a debug run of shell script? (Probably No way?)

Comment: Pipe it through sed and replace the password with xxxxx? Simple as that, or what are you asking?

Comment: Can you share some sample snippet of the strings which needs be hidden? (or) may be share a sample snippet output of the debug output and show us which need to be hidden

Comment: @Inian , the password comes as a variable, so when the script runs, it also shows the variable value, just like any script..I want to hide that... I'll try to add that as part of my question...

Comment: @Marcos: Yes that would be useful. I just need the variable name to exclude from being printed

Comment: @fancyPants , How can I do that within an executing script? Wint it change the value of variable?

Comment: @Marcos: Refer Cyrus's answer, if you want to exclude certain lines of code from being run in debug mode. What I was suggesting was something from the command line `bash -x script.sh | grep -v <exclude>` so that we can exclude strings from showing up. It is up to you to choose which one do you want

Comment: @Inian, the password value is not stagnant, as the passwords get updated all the time and mostly its alphanumeric w/o specials.

Comment: @Marcos: It makes sense, can you just share a snippet (without password string) to give us an idea of how it will look? Without that, there is no use of all these discussion here

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Disable debugging for the part with sensitive information and re-enable it afterwards.

```
if [[ $- =~ x ]]; then debug=1; set +x; fi

# your code with sensitive information

[[ $debug == 1 ]] && set -x
```

Comment: Yes, that means changes before and after the sensitive parts of the code.