# Exception to `set -e` in bash

Tags: bash, continuous-integration

I have a bash script used to make my project. I have `set -e` in top of the script to break the execution when any component fails.

One of the commands would fail, but it is natural for it to fail. I would like the script to behave as such:

- Run the script.
- Reach and run the problematic command.
- If it fails, don't break execution. Do this ONLY for this command.

Comment: Recommended reading: [BashFAQ/105](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest:

```
set +e
# your command which would fail
set -e
```

or

```
your_command_which_would_fail || true
```

Comment: Your first proposal would mean to switch `set -e` on after this command *even if it wasn't on before it* (i. e. in another context, after a patch, whatever).

Comment: @Alfe: This is also possible with -e and +e: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48019999/3776858

Comment: Yes, with more code.  So I would not propose it for this usecase.

Comment: Wow, thanks both @Alfe and @Cyrus for the prompt reply. I went with the `|| true` option.

Answer (score 2):

The flag `set -e` has a bunch of exemptions where it doesn't lead to an abort right away after an executed command failed (exitcode ≠ 0).  Among these are the connections as @cyrus proposed (`a || b` and similar).  See `man bash` for details; it's kind of hard to find, maybe this helps:

```
man bash | grep -B 20 -A 10000 'Exit.*immediately' | less
```

My proposal would be to put it in an `if`:

```
if command
then
    : "worked nicely"
else
    : "failed, but we don't want to abort"
fi
```

or @Cyrus's short version:

```
command || true  # do not abort in case of 'set -e'
```